# as.integer(8952) = 8951?

Tags: r, integer, determinants

I accidentally discovered a weird bug with either the `as.integer` or the `det` function in R base. Does anyone know what is going on here and how to prevent it?

I was computing the determinant of the following 3-by-3 matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(c(15, 6, 116, 10, 13, 16, 14, 23, 56), ncol = 3)
```

Which looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   15   10   14
[2,]    6   13   23
[3,]  116   16   56
```

Two things are easy to see: all entries are integers, and each of the six sets of three-entries-no-two-of-which-lie-in-the-same-row-or-column contains at least one even integer. Hence the determinant must be an even integer.

Asking R the actual value of this determinant by typing `det(mat)` it returns something that looks like an even integer: `8952`. But lo and behold: deep down inside R's mind it actually is either a non-integer or an odd integer, since when typing `as.integer(det(mat))` we get `8951`.

What is going on here? The 8951 is obviously wrong. Also, less obviously, the value 8952 is correct as can be seen with pen and paper.

So my questions are:

1. what is going on here?
2. How do I force R to give me the **correct** integer values when asked to compute the determinant of an integer matrix?

Comment: Use `round(det(mat))` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Underlying causes: Truncation by `is.integer` rather than rounding and floating point math on logged intermediate values to explain the second result, combined with the default digit level of display in the  `print` portion of the console REPL to explain the initial result of `det(mat)`:

```
print( det(mat), digits =16)
[1] 8951.999999999993
```

It's quite possible that the theoretic answer is 8952 but R is not a symbolic math engine.

[image]

You can use the Rmpfr package (as suggested by @BenBolker) to increase the level of precision:

```
 library(Rmpfr)
 mat <- mpfr(mat, 64)
 as.integer( det(mat) )
[1] 8952
```

`as.integer` truncates rather than rounds. See `?as.integer`. R would be able to handle addition or multiplication of integers without loss of precision but as soon as division occurs there is likely to be floating point error. (Actually the problem arises because the default for `det` is to use `determinant` with `log=TRUE` and then exponentiate the modulus of the complex result.) From the Values section of the help page:

> Non-integral numeric values are truncated towards zero (i.e., `as.integer(x)` equals `trunc(x)` there), and imaginary parts of complex numbers are discarded (with a warning).

Comment: is there a solution to question 2? (rounding? using `Rmpfr` ?)

Comment: This doesn't make it any less mysterious though, does it? For one: why is as.integer(8951.999999999993) = 8951 rather than 8952? Why does it not round to the nearest integer? And second: I get that computers cannot represent fractions exactly but why would they have trouble with integers?

Comment: `as.integer` truncates rather than rounds. See `?as.integer`

Comment: Ok thanks, this also explains the other comment about using round rather than as.integer. Perhaps I will ask a separate question about the floating point issue

Comment: Your last sentence [EDIT: it is no longer the last. The one about addition and multiplication vs division] hits the nail on the head of what I still don't understand. It is easy to compute determinants without division. If R somehow smuggles some division into the computation this is quite cumbersome as it is setting itself up for exactly this type of error...

Comment: From the `det` help page: "The determinant function uses an LU decomposition and the `det` function is simply a wrapper around a call to `determinant`.

Often, computing the determinant is not what you should be doing to solve a given problem."

Comment: @Vincent, R does not prioritize precise solutions to small integer problems; it prioritizes efficient solutions to large numerical (floating-point) problems, e.g. `determinant(matrix(rnorm(1e6),1000),log=TRUE)`